# C# How to return string instead of DateTime using Partial class

Tags: c#, partial-classes

In my silverLight project I have a class on web side with few DateTime fields. I want to write Partial class for the class on client side which will return string instead of DateTime. How to write it?

This is what I tried. I added new string variable in Partial class which will get date field's and return string.

here is code:

```
public partial class abcd 
{
  DateTime date1;
  public DateTime Date1
    {
        get { return date1; }
        set { date1 = value; }
    }
  DateTime date2;
  public DateTime Date2
    {
        get { return date2; }
        set { date2 = value; }
    }
}
public partial class abcd
{
  string date1Str;
  public string Date1Str
    {
        get { return Date1Str; }
        set { date2 = Date1.ToString(MM/dd/yyyy); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a trivial task so I'm sure there is something hidden here.

Comment: Can you post some code sample?

Comment: I'm not sure what a partial class has to do with returning strings instead of DateTime... The concepts seem orthogonal.

Comment: I have edited my code Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `Date1Str` should be readonly and just look like this:

```
public string Date1Str
{
    get { return date1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); }
}
```